# android error in listview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

```js
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >
 
    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
 
    <!-- Movie Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
 
    <!-- Rating -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />
     
    <!-- Genre -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />
 
    <!-- Release Year -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year" />
 
</RelativeLayout>
```

```js
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
}
```

please tell what to do? whenever i tried to inflate the list_row, it shows that list_row cannot be resolved or is not a field . please tell what to do? whenever i tried to inflate the list_row, it shows that list_row cannot be resolved or is not a field .

Comment: Is this the whole getView method? Is list_row.xml the first code snippet you posted? Is it located in the res/layout folder?

Comment: sorry my bad...yeah the first snippet is list_row.xml and it is located in res/layout folder.

Comment: have you imported the correct R file. Maybe you have imported android.R instead of your own projects R file?

Answer (score 0):

I re-edit my answer
try to change your  Context;

change your context in the inflater to "context" instead of activity ,these the two method to get LayoutInflater:

getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

getContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);